# Wordpress: trigger plugin when scheduled post is published

Tags: php, wordpress

I developed this wordpress plugin to send a notification to a telegram channel when an article is published.

It works with immediate publishing, but I have some problems when a scheduled article is published

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'invia_notifica_telegram_schedulato', 10, 3);

function invia_notifica_telegram_schedulato($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    if (($old_status != 'publish') && ($new_status == 'publish' || $new_status == 'future')) {
        invia_notifica_telegram($post->ID, $post);
    }
}

function invia_notifica_telegram($post_id, $post) {
    if (($post->post_status == 'publish' || $post->post_status == 'future') && strtotime($post->post_date) <= current_time('timestamp')) {
        // Recupera il titolo e l'URL dell'articolo appena pubblicato
        $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);
        $post_url = get_permalink($post_id);
        
        // Recupera il contenuto del tag h2 dall'articolo
        $post_content = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
        preg_match('/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>/si', $post_content, $matches);
        $h2_content = isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : '';
        
        // Aggiungi un ritardo di 30 secondi
   //     sleep(30);
     
        // Invia il messaggio al bot Telegram
        invia_messaggio_telegram($post_title, $h2_content, $post_url);
    }
}

function invia_messaggio_telegram($title, $h2_content, $url) {
    // Imposta l'URL del bot Telegram e il chat ID
        $telegram_bot_token = 'XXXXXXXX';
        $telegram_chat_id = '-XXXXXXX';

    // Costruisci il messaggio da inviare
    $message = "$h2_content\n\n";
    $message .= "$url";

    // Invia il messaggio tramite cURL
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$telegram_bot_token/sendMessage";
    $data = array('chat_id' => $telegram_chat_id, 'text' => $message, 'parse_mode' => 'HTML');
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
}
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks
Marco

The notification always starts when an article is published (both immediately and scheduled)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use the `post_publish` and `future_to_publish` hooks instead:

```
function post_publish(int $id, \WP_Post $post) {
  invia_notifica_telegram($post->ID, $post);
}
add_action('publish_post', 10, 2);

function scheduled_post_published(\WP_Post $post) 
{
  invia_notifica_telegram($post->ID, $post);
}
add_action('future_to_publish', 'scheduled_post_published');
```